# What are the options for integrating an external scheduler with Slurm to enhance job management?

Tags: scheduler, slurm, hpc, lsf

How to integrate an external scheduler with Slurm for enhanced job management? I want to have control over node selection(out of available candidate nodes I want to decide which nodes and cpu to go with hence slot identification too). Also is there any way to hold job scheduling for a job and resume it from some plugin or external scheduler?

Plugins seem to be a way but it seems plugin/sched doesn't have relevant APIs.